# Is $X$ a subspace of $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $u=(1,0,2)$ and $X=\{w \in \mathbb{R}^3 : wu=0\}$, is $X$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

If it is then how do you figure out the spanning set for $X$?

Comment: what is your definition of vector product? Dot-product, or cross-product, or...?

Answer (score 1):

Your set is the collection of all vectors *perpendicular* to $u$. Remember that for any $u$, $0\cdot u=0 $ and $u\cdot(w+v)=u\cdot w+u\cdot v$ (i.e. the distributive law).

Can you visualize what the set is? Can you guess or prove what is its dimension? Once you know this, can you find vectors in your set that are linearly independent and span it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you meant $\langle w, u \rangle  = 0$, you can see that $X = \ker w^T$, and since the kernel is a subspace, it follows that $X$ is too.

To figure out a basis for $\ker w^T$, find two linearly independent elements of $X$. You can do this in many ways (Grahm Schmidt applied to vectors $u, e_1,e_2,e_3$, for example), but direct computation is probably easiest here.

The equation is $x_1+2x_3 = 0$. Clearly $(0,1,0)$ satisfies this, and so does $(2,0,-1)$. And it is easy to see that these are linearly independent (in fact, they are orthogonal).

To see that it is spanning, suppose $x \in X$, that is $x_1+2x_3 = 0$. The you can see that $(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_2 (0,1,0) - x_3 (2,0,-1)$, hence $X = \operatorname{sp} \{ (0,1,0) ,(2,0,-1) \}$.